# Несколько верных ответов

Tags: предложение, вопросы, ответы, принятые-ответы

Порой бывает, что на один вопрос даётся несколько верных, но и в то же время РАЗНЫХ ответов. Предлагаю для таких случаев добавить возможность помечать правильными несколько ответов.

P. S. Оно точно не должно распространяться на конкурсные вопросы.

Comment: Против. В конечном счёте, для решения реально возникшей проблемы автор выбирает **какой-то один** способ. Если этот способ основан на нескольких, он может быть достоин собственного ответа. А вводить новую механику с кучей исключений ради исчезающе редких ситуаций мне видится ненужным. Если считаете нужным наградить нескольких -- голосуйте за них. Мало -- сделайте конкурс.

Answer (score 8):

**Против**.

Стэковерфлоу не про правильные и неправильные ответы, а про полезные и вредные.

Голоса показывают мнение сообщества на этот счёт. У насущных вопросов бывает много ответов с высоким рейтингом, и каждый из этих ответов чем-то полезен.

Галкой автор вопроса обозначает, что больше помогло лично ему. Это может быть и самый заминусованный ответ.

А конкретного читателя может выручить ответ и непопулярный, и не отмеченный как решение.

Поэтому не надо слишком верить ни ответам, ни оценкам за ответы. Этот сайт помогает собирать варианты и узнавать, что думают о них другие. А каким из них воспользоваться, каждый решает для себя сам.