# Токсичность людей на stack overflow

Tags: обсуждение, правила, этикет

Я уже года три явлюсь участником данного сообщества, более активно учавствовать начал в этом году. Первые пару месяцев все было более менее хорошо. Но за последний месяць прямо комбо. Я не буду называть ники, но сейчас когда новичек задает глупый (по мнению некоторых участников) вопрос, его тупо начинают тролить, вместо того, чтобы объяснить автору вопроса ему советуют бросить программирования, пойти обратно в первый класс итд. Вместо того, чтобы объяснить с него стебуться, "вы сами не знаете что тут происходит"б "бросьте это дело и идите учите по урокам на ютьюбе". И так вопрос: **Зачем тогда в принципе лезть в этот вопрос, если вы понимаете, что у вас не хватит терпения на него полноценно ответить?!** Вы считаете своим долгом оставить свою метку над каждым вопросом? Зачем?

Далее. Существуют некоторые участники, которые тупо не воспринимают критику, от слова совсем. Не дай бог что то скажешь в сторону его идеального ответа. Они зайдут на твой профиль, пройдутся по всем твоим ответам, обкакают их в комментариях, отминусует. После чего спрашивают, ПОНЯЛ ЛИ ТЫ, ЧТО ИДЕАЛЬНЫХ ОТВЕТОВ НЕТУ, И ЧТО НЕФИГ ДОКАПЫВАТЬСЯ?! У человека и репутации приличное количество, но в который раз убеждаюсь, что она вообще не является гарантом того, что человек адекватен и стоит ему давать какие либо привелегии.

Третья проблема. Вот есть участники, которые чуть опоздали с ответом, при том что автор его принял, (новички обычно пишут спасибо вместо галочки), при этом, берут твой ответ и перефразовывают, но для того, чтобы показать кто здесь альфа в этом вопросе, берут и тупо пишут в комментах что ТВОЙ ответ не верный, все мы знаем тенденцию что очень многие минусуют вопросы\ответы руководясь только стадным инстинктом.

Что же меня подтолкнуло написать мне этот пост (который скорее всего удалят, но не суть), каким образом можно бороться с такими людьми? Может стоит как нибудь поменять логику начисления репутации, чтобы пропали люди, которые любыми средствами хотят ее повысить? Может придумать какой нибудь механизм наказания таких людей? к примеру за такое поведение не удалять его ответ\коммент а отнимать определенное количество репутации? Может таким образом можно заставить людей думать что они пишут и стоит ли оно того?

UPD: Ну хорошо, по мере нахождения таких случаев я буду сюда их кидать в виде ссылок\скриншотов. Не уверен насчет удаленных, они отображаются в ленте событий?

**Случай 1**

Вопрос о том, как можно обойти блокировку по айпи при парсинге страницы.
Я ответил, единственный вариант это прокси. на что пользователь @VictorVosMottor указал что нет, не единственный, есть же **VPN** и отправил меня гуглить на эту тему. [Вот собственно вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175276/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ip-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5/1175277?noredirect=1#comment2043934_1175277) так же советую проанализировать его ответ, и историю его изминений.

К сожелению не смог найти в ленте событий. Но суть в том, что после этих минусов и комментарий под всеми вопросами у меня бобануло, и в одном из комментариев я матернулся.
Но есть скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ссылка на чат [вот](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112779/discussion-between---and-victor-vosmottor)

Comment: Есть тревоги, много тревог - бан.

Comment: Ники в студию! Страна должна знать своих героев.

Comment: К людям надо относиться мягше, а на вопросы смотреть ширше ©

Comment: Ну и как вы предполагаете можно найти этих людей? Конкретные ссылки в студию

Comment: _который скорее всего удалят_ - между прочим, это тоже один из элементов токсичности: заранее обвинить всех в удалении своего идеального поста. | С самим сообщением я согласен, тема поднята хорошая. Плюс поставил.

Comment: То есть это вы были токсичны и сматерились почем зря?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Посмотрел ситуацию по третьей проблеме.

Судя по всему, участник просто спросил у вас,
что такое `Console.WriteLine` в контексте **VBA**(не VB.Net).

Вы же уже успели и тут же на него накричать: «прежде чем такую глупость писать», и под его ответ пришли с претензиями, будто у вас патент на умножение в цикле.

В общем, о чём мой ответ? Искоренять токсичность в сообществе надо начиная с себя.
Невозможно бороться с тем, в чём сам погряз по уши.

Научитесь абстрагироваться от происходящего и с холодным сердцем взгляните на это происходящее «со стороны».

- Так ли всё на самом деле, как показалось в первый момент?
- Улучшит ли ситуацию вот этот комментарий, который я уже набрал но не успел отправить? Может стоит его переписать? Или вообще в нём нет необходимости?

Ну и самое главное — пока это возможно, **предполагайте добрые намерения** участников сообщества.
Если участник не грубит явным образом, не нужно обвинять его в «скрытой пассивной гипертоксичности». Вероятно, это просто ваша интуиция дала сбой. Пользуйтесь презумпцией невиновности.

Comment: Вот, плюсану. Думал, что мы Вас совсем потеряли :) Хотя, много спорного и риторического в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 15):

По первой проблеме ничего особого сказать не могу. Да, такое случается, но не я бы сказал что часто вижу подобное. В комментариях правильно написали - ставьте тревоги.

Хотя полностью проблему не изжить никак: вы вот на наличие комментариев жалуетесь, а другие участники - [на их отсутствие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277). Однако, одно неизменно - всегда будут вопросы, которым не рады на этом сайте, и авторы этих вопросов всегда будут обвинять сообщество в токсичности.

---

По второму вопросу - не обращайте внимание на подобных участников. Если в комментариях совсем уж "обгавкивание" - есть тревоги, но если комментарии по делу - пусть будут.

Хотя знаете что сделал бы я в такой ситуации? Я бы исправил все выявленные недочёты, и поблагодарил бы незванного редактора за его титанический труд по улучшению качества моих ответов :-)

---

По третьему вопросу. А вот тут уже вы не правы, притом сразу во многом.

Во-первых, то что автор принял ответ, ещё ничего не означает. Автор вопроса, как правило, не является специалистом в той области в которой он задаёт вопрос, и он не может оценить качество ответа.

Во-вторых, правило "кто первый встал, того и тапки" тут не работает. То, что вы успели первым дать ответ, даёт вам небольшой бонус за счёт того что вам "плюсы" начали ставить раньше, но не даёт никаких особых прав.

В-третьих, не факт что стадный инстинкт действительно работает на этом сайте. Но даже если бы работал - он был бы на вашей стороне, ведь ваш ответ первый начал собирать плюсы.

В-четвёртых, в ответе важно не только содержание, но и форма. И если чужой ответ набирает больше плюсов чем ваш - значит, его сочли более понятным, а это тоже важно для ответа.

Answer (score 11):

Я на сайте уже 5 лет, и ещё не разу не видел тут вменяемое применение термина "токсичный". Каждый раз его пытаются применить в оправдание себя или чтобы уличить коллегу, и каждый раз ситуация неоднозначная.

Далее, вы описываете проблемы, которых нет.

> его тупо начинают тролить, вместо того, чтобы объяснить автору вопроса ему советуют бросить программирования, пойти обратно в первый класс итд

Считаете, что комментарий неуместный - отметье флагом. Хотите сделать на шаг больше - вежливо поясните автору комментария свю позицию, не ввязываясь в дискуссию. Все, больше ничего делать не надо.

> Зачем тогда в принципе лезть в этот вопрос, если вы понимаете, что у вас не хватит терпения на него полноценно ответить?!

А кто судить будет, есть ли у человека нужные знания / терпение или нет. Вы? Вы не можете указывать другим, что им делать. Если они нарушают правила - дайте знать модераторам. Если они не нарушают правила, но вам такие люди нериятны - не ввязывайтесь с ними в дискуссию.

> Существуют некоторые участники, которые тупо не воспринимают критику

Это не лечится. Примите это. Если вы считаете, что вопрос или ответ недостоин того, чтобы существовать или не точен - у вас есть возможность сделать правку / поставить минус / оставить комментарий. Вступать в заведомо тупиковую дискуссию и разыгрывать вендетты нет смысла.

> У человека и репутации приличное количество, но в который раз убеждаюсь, что она вообще не является гарантом того, что человек адекватен и стоит ему давать какие либо привелегии.

У человека репутация, потому что за его вопросы/ответы проголосовало сообщество. Здесь голосуют за полезность информации, а не потому что "человек хороший". Высокая репутация не говорит ничего о человеке, кроме того, что он может писать вопросы или ответы (а может и хорошо гуглить и копипсастить). Потому расчитывать, что высокореповый участник будет с вами галантен весьма наивно.

> Вот есть участники, которые чуть опоздали с ответом, при том что автор его принял

Нет такого понятия как "опоздал с ответом". Вы можете написать ответ на вопрос любой давности и он может быть принят.

> каким образом можно бороться с такими людьми?

Цель сайта - создание базы вопросов и ответов. Если участник пишет вопросы/ответы и не нарушает правила сайта, то бороться с таким участником нужно только вам. Больше никому это не нужно.

Также хочется сказать по поводу токсичности. Я, за время, что провел тут, написал очень много ответов и ещё больше комментариев. Я очень ценю свое время и предпочитаю тратить его только на то, что интересно и важно лично мне. Потому, к примеру, когда я общаюсь с другими участниками, я не делаю реверансов и не проявляю излишнюю вежливость - моя цель больше донести свою мысль, чем менять формулировки своих комментариев, лишь бы не нанести вред нежной душе собеседника. Это не означает, что я хочу его обидеть или оскорбить, даже если собеседнику так может показаться. Потому ваши суждения, что кто то что то пишет, чтобы показать, что он "альфа"- может быть верно, а может быть и плодом вашего воображения, как и все остальные описанные вами проблемы.

Вы, в своем вопросе, уже и выводы сделали и бороться собрались с вероятно воображаемым противником. Так это не работает. Если вы видите конкретную несправедливость - указывайте все детали, ссылки, скрины и пр, чтобы сообщество, модераторы или просто неравнодушные люди могли помочь разобраться в ситуации. Если эта несправедливость систематическая и вредит сайту - тут уже должна работать администрация.

Как общий совет - учитесь держать себя в руках. Учитесь не тратить свое время на бесполезные для вас разговоры. Решите ля себя зачем вы на сайте - чтобы бодаться с людьми, что вам не нравятся или чтобы помогать тем, кому нужна ваша помощь?

Comment: Я давно думал как написать ответ на этот вопрос. Теперь писать не придется. спасибо.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Спасибо! Рад, что вы со мной согласны.

Answer (score 7):

Вадим, мне сложно судить о проблемах в сообществе, но раз это обсуждение, выскажу свое мнение и постараюсь аргументировать.

> ... когда новичек задает глупый (по мнению некоторых участников) вопрос, его тупо начинают тролить, вместо того, чтобы объяснить автору вопроса ему советуют бросить программирования, пойти обратно в первый класс итд.

Возможно, новичку стоит провести поиск ответа, как это рекомендуют в справке сообщества, в разделе "[как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", там также есть примеры того, как лучше формулировать вопрос. Если новичок напишет:

> Искал тут-то (ссылка на первый сайт) и там-то (второй сайт), но это не помогло, потому что у меня проблема конкретно вот с (описание проблемы)

Я думаю, что такие комментарии никто оставлять не будет.

По поводу

> автору советуют бросить программирования, пойти обратно в первый класс и
> т.д.

Никогда такого не встречал, хотя являюсь участником сообщества уже 2 года и активно задаю вопросы. Возможно, кто-то действительно высказался грубо, тогда есть механизм [тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Но, стоит также с холодной головой проанализировать, почему был оставлен такой комментарий. Возможно, это связано с тем, что автор нарушает правила русского языка в тексте вопроса. Такие посты неприятно читать.

Если Вы видите орфографические ошибки в вопросе или ответе, пожалуйста, предложите правку и исправьте их, помогите автору.
Многое подчеркивает здешний редактор (например, правильно писать новичок, а не новичек). Я пользуюсь для проверки орфографии сервисом [text.ru](https://text.ru/spelling) он помогает отловить несоответствие падежей и досадные ошибки с `-тся/-ться`. Советую искренне, без троллинга, ведь Вам, уверен, тоже не хочется тратить свое время на ответ, если вопрос был сформулирован "на отвали".

Далее

> Зачем тогда в принципе лезть в этот вопрос, если вы понимаете, что у
> вас не хватит терпения на него полноценно ответить?

Если вопрос тривиальный, он скорее всего плохо сформулирован (руководствуясь примерами из справки плохо). [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204416/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) такого вопроса. Согласитесь, такого вопроса бы у автора не возникло, если бы он погуглил. А лезть в такие вопросы надо, чтобы их [закрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

> Существуют некоторые участники, которые тупо не воспринимают критику,
> от слова совсем. Не дай бог что то скажешь в сторону его идеального
> ответа. Они зайдут на твой профиль, пройдутся по всем твоим ответам,
> обкакают их в комментариях, отминусует. После чего спрашивают, ПОНЯЛ
> ЛИ ТЫ, ЧТО ИДЕАЛЬНЫХ ОТВЕТОВ НЕТУ, И ЧТО НЕФИГ ДОКАПЫВАТЬСЯ?!

Страшно! Воспользуйтесь тревогой "требуется вмешательство модератора", таким людям не место в сообществе. Но с таким не сталкивался.

> Вот есть участники, которые чуть опоздали с ответом, при том что автор
> его принял, (новички обычно пишут спасибо вместо галочки), при этом,
> берут твой ответ и перефразовывают, но для того, чтобы показать кто
> здесь альфа в этом вопросе, берут и тупо пишут в комментах что ТВОЙ
> ответ не верный

Проанализируйте ответ другого участника. Возможно, он дополнил Ваш, предложил другой способ решения проблемы. Попросите комментатора развернуто объяснить, почему, по его мнению, Ваш ответ не решает проблему автора. Может быть другой участник укажет Вам на ошибку в коде или на другую причину. Поддерживаю точку зрения, что верных или неверных ответов на этом сайте не бывает, как сказал [@Gleb Kemarsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208926/gleb-kemarsky) в ответе на [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4110/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) предложение на мете.

Ну и последнее

> все мы знаем тенденцию что очень многие минусуют вопросы\ответы
> руководясь только стадным инстинктом.

Обидно, что Вы так думаете о людях. Минус не способ унизить человека, а способ обратить внимание автора вопроса или ответа на плохую формулировку. Если минусов много, то это значит, что проблема, скорее всего, в вопросе/ответе. И, скорее всего, эта проблема и способы ее решить описаны в справке.

Comment: `Страшно! Воспользуйтесь тревогой "требуется вмешательство модератора", таким людям не место в сообществе. Но с таким не сталкивался.` — все он врет.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Я вру, или автор вопроса?

Comment: Автор конечно, вы то тут причем.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor вы мою цитату взяли, а не автора)) Если он врет, то тревогой он не воспользуется, а если не врет, будет знать о такой возможности.

Comment: Можете мой ответ прочитать, если вам интересно, что было ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну автор ники не указывал, так, что то, то его вопрос Вас так сильно задел, считаю избыточной реакцией. Я посоветовал воспользоваться помощью модераторов, так как именно это и следует сделать в общем случае. Конкретно в Вашей ситуации, я никакого не заслуженного "обкакивания" не вижу. В конце концов, "В малых дозах яд — лекарство" (с) и указать, что такие участники не правы надо по моему мнению))

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответам [@vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11104/6) и [@Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11106/6)

#### Токсичность людей на Stack Overflow

Эволюция подарила нам инстинкты, которыми довольно сложно управлять в стрессовых ситуациях. К примеру, мы неосознанно можем вести себя в стиле «бей-или-беги», когда чувствуем страх отречения от группы (то есть когда нам кажется, что кто–то покушается на наше положение в обществе). Добавляем недопонимания, поменьше эмпатии, немного публики вокруг и получаем рецепт для потенциального выяснения отношений.

Другими словами, на мой взгляд, подавляющее большинство участников нашего сообщества — отличные люди, а зачастую еще и крутые спецы в своей области. Если вы попали в неоднозначную ситуацию, пожалуйста, поставьте себя на место коллеги, которому вы помогаете или просите о помощи и следуйте совету [@vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11104/6) – предполагать добрые намерения. Мы все собрались на сайте с общей целью — создать базу знаний сообщества по всем прикладным вопросам по программированию.

Если вы видите, что разрешить ситуацию не получается — задайте вопрос на Мете.

#### Дьявол кроется в деталях

Одна из главных функций Меты — обсуждение модерации сайта. Рассматривая *конкретные примеры* вместе, мы шаг за шагом делаем правила нашего сообщества лучше. При публикации таких вопросов, [обязательно описывайте все дели рассматриваемой проблемы, сосредоточившись на поведении, а не участнике](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). В случае обсуждения без конкретных примеров, на мой взгляд, можно прийти к ситуации в которой оказались [слепые мудрецы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD): глядя на одно событие, мы все будем видеть совершенно разное.

#### Оставляйте тревогу на сообщениях нарушающих нормы поведения или правила сообщества

Когда–то давно, [@etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki) написал [прекрасный вопрос со своим ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/6), который впоследствии [стал страницей справки](/help/be-friendly). Если вы видите [подшучивание в любом виде](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2349/6), пожалуйста, помечайте такие комментарии тревогой. Если тревоги отклоняются, задайте вопрос на Мете или напишите [в поддержку](/contact).

#### То, как вы подсказываете, не менее важно, чем суть самой подсказки

Чтобы ваши рекомендации помогли участнику, первое что необходимо — чтобы человек захотел, им следовать. Другими словами, подача не менее важна, чем содержание, особенно, когда вы хотите сообщить кому–либо о сделанных недочетах.

#### Получая отзыв, подразумевается добрый намерения

С другой стороны, получая отзыв, помните, что, с большой вероятностью, другой участник хочет вам чем–либо помочь, но, возможно, выбрал не лучший способ донести свою мысль. В случае недопонимания, переспросите, например, «Правильно ли я понял, что вы рекомендуете использовать X, а не Y?»